# Open avi file with OpenCV : ffmpeg?

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg, codec

This question is related to a previous question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194713/open-and-read-avi-files-with-opencv-ubuntu).

I read on the Willow Garage website dedicated to OpenCV that we do not have to take care of ffmpeg while installing OpenCV since version 1.2.x. [Here it is](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/FFMPEG).

However, some [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075180/how-to-compile-opencv-2-3-with-ffmpeg-support-with-visual-studio-2010) asked here on Stackoverflow suggest the contrary.

So, what should I do ? Do I have to recompile OpenCV and do some special operation related to ffmpeg to get it to, finally, open avi file on my Linux system ?

Comment: 32 bits Linux Ubuntu 11.04, I work with Qt Creator, OpenCV 2.4.

Comment: Did you compile OpenCV with option `WITH_QT=ON`?

Comment: I'm not sure, but how is this related to OpenCV and the it opens avi files ? Except for this avi thing, my OpenCV+Qt application work just fine.

Comment: [You can use Qt as HighGUI backend on any platforms (Windows, Linux, Mac) by passing WITH_QT=ON to CMake when configuring OpenCV.](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide)

Comment: OK this is very interesting, really, however my problem is about codec, ffmpeg, and the way it should be handled to read avi files with OpenCV... that's all. I don't see how my problem is related to Qt. I only use Qt to design my GUIs. I want only one thing actually, figuring out how to open avi files with my OpenCV application, and I thought ffmpeg was part of the problem.

Comment: OpenCV HighGUI respones for UI, simple video input/output. If you want to use QT as HighGUI than you obviously have to build OpenCV with QT HighGUI support. That's it.

Comment: OK, but like I said my application is working just fine, I can display web cam, point grey camera and even kinect with it. avi files are the only thing that give me trouble. btw, I catch my frames using OpenCV, and then translate cv::Mat to QImage to display them in the GUI. So Qt is used at the very end. So you see, I don't really use Qt as HighGUI to open avi... I'm so upset with this.

Comment: BTW, I just read CMakeLists.txt, Qt is OFF and FFMPEG is ON  by default.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.
FFMPEG is indeed ON by default, since OpenCV 1.2.x according to Willow Garage. Which means that you do not have to take care of it. 
Then, what I tried to explain to Astor, and then confirmed without a doubt by recompiling OpenCV with WITH_QT=ON, is that Qt had nothing to do with this issue. 
The video "just" had to be encoded in a particular format, which is MPEG-4 XVID. I used mencoder to convert my file.